# Azure CLI - Will "az ad" be updated to use Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, azure-cli

`az ad app permission add` needs Azure Active Directory Graph - Application.ReadWrite.All:
[az ad app permission add - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185434/az-ad-app-permission-add-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation)

However, Azure AD Graph API is being deprecated. Will az ad at some point be updated to use Microsoft Graph API instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this comment from a member of the Azure cli team, they plan to migrate az ad to MS Graph: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946#issuecomment-737196942

> Azure CLI team is currently working on the ADAL -> MSAL migration. We
> will start the planning and implementation of Active Directory Graph
> -> Microsoft Graph migration once the previously task is done. + @achandmsft

Comment: According to the latest comment it seems that the team has started working on this but it will take some time: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946#issuecomment-954742775. "This feature is already planned as top priority and we will work on it for several months. The rough ETA is by the end of March next year."

Answer (score 2):

`az ad` manage **Azure Active Directory Graph** entities needed for Role Based Access Control. And it is still using AD Graph API but not the new Microsoft Graph API. You could feedback to [UserVoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory).

You could call Microsoft Graph API with [`az rest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_rest) in Azure CLI, see [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/issues/12946).

> Since Microsoft Graph Service Principal API is GA, we recommend using
> `az rest` instead of `az ad` for the time being until we fully migrate `az ad` to Microsoft Graph.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by adding required role to service principle.

You don't require AAD graph permissions. You need to add the service principal to the [Global Administrator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/directory-assign-admin-roles#directory-readers) Role using **Azure portal->Azure AD->Roles and Administrators->Application Administrator**
[image]