# Get-AzADApplication Insufficient privileges to complete the operation in azure devop

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory

In my azure devop, I am using Azure PowerShell task and run this:

```
$app = Get-AzADApplication -ObjectId $appObjectId
```

This is failing and I see error
**`Get-AzADApplication : Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.`**

I can see from log, these are run before calling my code

```
2021-03-16T12:15:02.0180171Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope CurrentUser -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
2021-03-16T12:15:02.9752631Z ##[command]Clear-AzContext -Scope Process
2021-03-16T12:15:03.4700483Z ##[command]Connect-AzAccount -ServicePrincipal -Tenant *** -Credential System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -Environment AzureCloud @processScope
2021-03-16T12:15:05.6845552Z ##[command] Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId c5ffe1d4-c935-4559-9d67-5ea6546a8ec2 -TenantId ***
```

[image]
From this subscription, I can trace the SPN in azure portal and I already set as many permission as I can think of. But it still says not enough privileges.
[image]

In the azure AD, for

What am I missing?

Comment: It could be that the task doesn't setup the authentication correctly for the AzureAD module, just the Az module.

Comment: @juunas found answer in another question

Comment: Ah of course, it uses the older API :\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure AD is rather confusing. I found answer in this question

[az ad app permission add - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185434/az-ad-app-permission-add-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation)

As that answer, apparently Microsoft Graph doesn't work and you will have to add it under Azure Active Directory Graph, the so called legacy API.

Comment: Hi daxu, Thanks for the sharing, you could Accept it as an Answer, it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thank you very much.