# Azure Runbook and Insufficient Privileges with Get-AzADApplication -

Tags: azure, azure-runbook

I was hoping to get some advice on the following issue:
I am using System-assigned identity in my automation account for authentication. The role assignment for that system-assigned identity is "Owner" and the Scope is "Subscription".

When I run this command "Connect-AzAccount -Identity" - everything works as expected. However, the next command which is the second one in the script - "Get-AzADApplication" -fails with "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.".

Why am I unable to list all the applications under my tenant when my system managed identity has the "Owner" role? What am I missing here?

Comment: try with `-debug` option to get some logs what's happening there

Comment: @AatifAkhter Thank you! I tried your suggestion and I got:  "code": "Authorization_RequestDenied". 
Caught exception, type: Microsoft.Azure.Graph.RBAC.Models.GraphErrorException

However, I gave my system-assigned identity permissions to use Microsoft Graph
Read and write directory data, which I believe should allow it to retrieve AD data?

Comment: owner roles are more into azure rbac, but here you are dealing with graph API which is a different service than azure sub (rbac) . May I know how could you provide the graph read permissions to your system assigned identity?

Comment: @Jayendran I followed this document - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scenario-secure-app-access-microsoft-graph-as-app?tabs=azure-powershell%2Cprogramming-language-csharp, and used the script under "Grant access to Microsoft Graph" to provide the permissions.

Comment: hmm. looks like an ad vs graph API thing but not sure. 1.can you try to give the legacy [ad application API permission](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66656268/7073340) instead of Microsoft graph API?
2. Try the rest API (invoke-restapi) to call the graph API directly 
This will rule out if the issue is due to the graph vs ad thing

Comment: Can you please try adding Directory.Read.All permission to it as well .. in the script it has only User.Read.All

Comment: @MarkT were you able to follow what I mentioned. Any update?