# Give Managed Identity permission to create app registration in Azure AD via ARM Template Deployment Script

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template, azure-cli

**What we are trying to accomplish:**

We are using Azure ARM Templates to deploy new applications. When we deploy these new applications, we need to register them with our Azure AD for authentication purposes. We would like to include this app registration in our template along with the deployment of the application resources.

It looks like Azure Deployment Scripts are the way to register new apps with Azure AD in our ARM template. In our Deployment Script, the "scriptContent" I am attempting to run is simply `az ad app create --display-name ${appName}`

**The Problem**

Permissions. We are getting `DeploymentScriptError: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation`. I proceeded to create a Managed Identity and added `az login --identity -u ${managedIdentityId}` at the beggining of the script but the same error persisted. It seems the managed identity does not have permission to create an app registration and I am unsure how to give it this permission

I found [this article](https://moimhossain.com/2020/04/03/azure-ad-app-via-arm-template-deployment-scripts/) which provides a PowerShell script for granting the necessary permissions to the managed identity, however, the author does not explain what "GraphAppId" is or where it is coming from.

Any help with this would be tremendously appreciated

We are pretty new to ARM templates but this is what we currently have:

**main.bicep**

```
targetScope = 'subscription'

param location string = 'eastus'


resource myResourceGroup 'Microsoft.Resources/resourceGroups@2021-04-01' = {
  name: 'rg-test1'
  location: location
}

resource managedId 'Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities@2018-11-30' existing = {
  name: 'mi-deployscripttest'
  scope: resourceGroup('DefaultResourceGroup-EUS')
}

module deploymentScript 'modules/deploymentScript.bicep' = {
  scope: myResourceGroup
  name: 'deploymentScript'
  params: {
    appName: 'testApp1'
    location: location
    managedIdentityId: managedId.id
    managedIdentityPrincipalId: managedId.properties.principalId
  }
}
```

**deploymentScript.bicep**

```
param location string 
param appName string
param managedIdentityId string
param managedIdentityPrincipalId string

var scriptContent = format('''
  az login --identity -u {0}
  az ad app create --display-name {1}
''', managedIdentityId, appName)


resource deploymentScriptRoleDefinition 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions@2018-01-01-preview' = {
  name: guid('basicDeploymentScriptDefinition')
  properties: {
    roleName: 'deployment-script-minimum-privilege-for-deployment-principal'
    description: 'Configure least privilege for the deployment principal in deployment script'
    type: 'customRole'
    permissions: [
      {
        actions: [
          'Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/*'
          'Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups/*'
          'Microsoft.Resources/deployments/*'
          'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts/*'
          'Microsoft.Storage/register/action'
        ]
      }
    ]
    assignableScopes: [
      resourceGroup().id
    ]
  }
}

resource deploymentScriptRoleAssignment 'Microsoft.Authorization/roleAssignments@2015-07-01' = {
  name: guid('basicDeploymentScriptAssignment')
  properties: {
    principalId: managedIdentityPrincipalId
    roleDefinitionId: deploymentScriptRoleDefinition.id
  }
}

resource deploymentScript 'Microsoft.Resources/deploymentScripts@2020-10-01' = {
  name: 'deploymentScriptTest1'
  location: location
  kind: 'AzureCLI'
  identity: {
    type: 'UserAssigned'
    userAssignedIdentities: {
      '${managedIdentityId}': {}
    }
  }
  properties: {
    azCliVersion: '2.9.1'
    retentionInterval: 'P1D'
    scriptContent: scriptContent
    cleanupPreference: 'Always'
  }
  dependsOn: [ 
    deploymentScriptRoleAssignment 
  ] 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To find the **ClientID/AppID**, you need to check the request being sent to `https://login.microsoftonline.com` for authentication. **ClientID/AppID** is sent as a parameter in the request url as highlighted in **sample request** below:

https://login.microsoftonline.com/xxxxxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?**client_id=d736a5a0-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-d192b45e4aa7**&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms&state=1234&response_mode=query&scope=openid

To add required permissions in the token, you need to first copy the **Client ID (aka App ID)** that you are using in your request to get the Access Token and then navigate to:

**Azure Portal > Azure Active Directory > App Registration > All Applications > Search with the ClientID/AppID** copied earlier

In that application Navigate to:

Api Permissions > Add a permission > Microsoft Graph > Delegated permissions > Expand User > Select required permissions as shown below. Once the permissions are added, click on Grant Admin Consent for your_tenant button.

[image]

You can refer to [Insufficient privileges to complete the operation" while using Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/197819/34insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operatio.html), [Calling your APIs with Azure AD Managed Service Identity using application permissions](https://joonasw.net/view/calling-your-apis-with-aad-msi-using-app-permissions) and [az ad app permission add - Insufficient privileges to complete the operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59185434/az-ad-app-permission-add-insufficient-privileges-to-complete-the-operation)