# How to register a web app in Azure AD using Azure Pipelines?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-pipelines, azure-cli

I'm trying to deploy Azure resources using Bicep templates and Azure Pipelines.
So far I managed to deploy a web app, but I'm struggling to register it in Azure AD.

There is a job in my pipeline which should create an app in Azure AD:
[image: job in Azure pipeline]

This job fails with the following error:

> ERROR: Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.

I also tried to use **az rest** command like so
[image: az rest command]
and got similar error:

> ERROR: Forbidden({"error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","message":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation.","innerError":{"date":"2022-03-01T07:18:30","request-id":"903fcd87-ad15-4766-8f31-132185e2c97d","client-request-id":"903fcd87-ad15-4766-8f31-132185e2c97d"}}})

It's clear that the service connection used by the pipeline doesn't have some necessary permissions, but I cannot figure out which one.

The service connection has the **Owner** role. Here are API permissions of the service connection:
[image: api permissions]

There is an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59187708/17156297) to similar question suggesting that I need the **Application.ReadWrite.All** in **Azure AD Graph**, but Azure AD is deprecated:
[image: azure ad deprecation]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: The app havent been granted permissions. In your first screenshot,you can see 2 warning icons. You need a global admin to grant consent first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Microsoft Graph instead and select the appropriate permissions there.

[image]

Another option would be to let the bicep template of the web app add a system managed identity for you by using the SystemAssigned in the identity property:

```
 resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig:{
      alwaysOn: true
    }
    httpsOnly: true  
    clientAffinityEnabled: false
  }
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As you said I used the 2nd option with a system managed identity. This way I even can create role assignments with my Bicep files.